# unfortunately app has stopped in android emulator after adding webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, webview

I am trying to build a android application which takes input[array values] from java and passing to java script and html file. I have created with web view concept. But when i execute app is not working. here is the code. HTML file will take array values and plot graph

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;


import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
WebView webview;
final class ChartDataLoader{
@JavascriptInterface
public double[][] getData(){ double[][] data = { {10,10}, {20, 10} }; return data; }               
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new ChartDataLoader(), "dataLoader");
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
}
```

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chartcontainer">You should see a chart here.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

myData = dataLoader.getData(); 
alert("DataReceived: " + myData.length);
alert("Element 0 : " + myData[0]);

var myChart = new JSChart('chartcontainer', 'line');
myChart.setDataArray(myData);
myChart.draw();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post logcat error

Comment: i am not able to post because its too long for this field..

Comment: @user3335796 what is `DroidGap` where is webview initialized?

Comment: DroidGap is emulator name. Instead of activity i am using DroidGap

Comment: @user3335796 how can you use emulator name. It must be extends Actvity. Why is `//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` commented. WHere is webview initialized

Answer (score 0):

From your comments DroidGap is a emulator name.

So change to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

This

```
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // uncomment this
```

is commented

and `webview` is not initialized.

Example:

```
WebView webview;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); // missing
```